# How to fix 'Every time I turn on the computer and then the docker, I need to remove the containers, reset the docker and then make them

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

Every time I turn on the computer and then the docker, I need to remove the containers, reset the docker and then run `docker-compose up` because the containers don't work.

When I run the docker the containers are running but they don't work:

```
C:\docker\viland>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
db53a5054516        viland_apache           "/bin/sh -c 'apachec…"   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp      apache
2873985c23cc        viland_php              "docker-php-entrypoi…"   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         9000/tcp                         php
```

When trying to start containers, nothing changes:

```
Starting php        ... done
Starting apache     ... done
```

Every day to be able to work on the docker, I have to take the next steps:

1. `docker-compose down`,
2. then I restart the docker because I have information that the ports already allocated,
3. `docker-compose up`

Why do I need to remove containers for each and every one of them, do I need to re-create them?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        build: .docker/apache
        container_name: apache
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
          - .:/home/wwwroot/viland
        depends_on:
          - php

    php:
        build:
          context: .docker/php
          args:
            - WITH_XDEBUG=true
        env_file:
          - .env
        container_name: php
        volumes:
          - .:/home/wwwroot/viland
```

Comment: That `docker ps` output says the containers are running.  Can you provide a [mcve] showing exactly what steps you're running, including a small enough subset of your `docker-compose.yml` file to reproduce the issue, what command you're running, and what error you're getting?

Comment: ok, I will try.

Comment: As I understand you don't run `docker-compose down` and expect that it'll be handled automatically on turning off your computer, is that so?

Comment: yes, why should I create them every time?